# How to convert the ElasticSearch result into a parquet file?

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to convert the response from ElasticSearch `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchResponse<ObjectNode> response` to a parquet file by generating the schema dynamically...

I tried using Spark to create the parquet file dynamically, but it takes up a lot of heap space and is not memory efficient which resulted in a Memory out-of-bound exception as it exceeded the heap space while reading the JSON file and creating the data frame.

I was looking to convert the Elastic response to a parquet file directly where the schema could be generated dynamically...

I also saw that the schema is being generated dynamically by reading the first line of the record, but I'm not sure if this might work when the JSON response or elastic response has a hierarchy or nested structure.

Here's a code block for generating the schema of the parquet file dynamically through Spark.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AnalysisException {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
            .config("spark.master", "local")
            .getOrCreate();


    // create a data from the source
    Dataset<Row> dataframe =
            sparkSession
                    .read()
                    .json("async.json");

 //sparkSession.read().format("co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchResponse<ObjectNode>").load(response);


    // save the json as a parquet file, maintaining the schema information
    dataframe
            .write()
            .parquet("async.parquet");

    // after the parquet file is created
    // read the parquet file
    // parquet file is self-describing so the schema is preserved
    // the result of loading a parquet file is a also a Dataframe
    Dataset<Row> parquetFileDataFrame = sparkSession
            .read()
            .parquet("async.parquet");

    // parquet files are used to create temporary view and then used in SQL statements
    parquetFileDataFrame.createTempView("parquetFile");

    Dataset<Row> namesDataFrame = sparkSession
            .sql("SELECT * FROM parquetFile");
    namesDataFrame.show();
}
```

Here's the code block where I want to convert the response from ElasticSearch async scroll's response to a parquet file where the schema could be generated dynamically...

```
public Future<JsonObject> asyncScroll(File file, String index, Query query, String[] source,
  String searchId, ProgressListener progressListener) {
Promise<JsonObject> promise = Promise.promise();

SearchRequest searchRequest = SearchRequest
    .of(e -> e.index(index).query(query).size(10000).scroll(scr -> scr.time("5m")));
asyncClient.search(searchRequest, ObjectNode.class).whenCompleteAsync((response, ex) -> {
  if (ex != null) {

  }
  String scrollId=null;
  try {
    // LOGGER.info("response : {}",response.toString());
    scrollId = response.scrollId();

    Dataset<Row> dataframe =
          sparkSession
            .read()
            .format("String")
            .load(response.toString());
            
    dataframe
            .write()
            .parquet("async.parquet");

    Dataset<Row>  parquetFileDataFrame = sparkSession
            .read()
            .parquet("async.parquet");

    // parquet files are used to create temporay view and then used in SQL statements
    parquetFileDataFrame
            .createTempView("parquetFile");

    Dataset<Row>  namesDataFrame = sparkSession
            .sql("SELECT * FROM parquetFile");
    namesDataFrame.show();
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the snippet of what you tried?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson, sure... I've edited it to add code snippets

Comment: Spark has an Elasticsearch client already. Why use native Java client?

Comment: In any case, the problem with this code `sparksession.read().load()` accepts a **file path**, not a string variable in-memory

Comment: Oh okay, @OneCricketeer you're right... I was looking at Spark support in Elasticsearch (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html). Are there any other places where I could learn more about it as I feel the Java implementation for Spark is kinda vague?

Comment: More about what? That is the official documentation. Scala/Java/Python can all access the same classes in Spark. That page tells you how to create a dataframe and see its schema - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-sql-read-java

Comment: I meant more about writing the ElasticSearch response into a parquet file and if there are some methods that could allow me to add the schema dynamically